# Список окон в KDE

Tags: kde, shell, linux

Какой командой в KDE можно получить список открытых окон? Нужна команда/утилита для использования в скрипте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/)

[Google: wmctrl полно разговоров по сабжу](http://www.google.ru/search?q=wmctrl)